# Angular reactive forms disabled group

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using Angular reactive forms. On my page I need to optionally enable/disable fields (current password and new password + confirmation) so that I could use `form.value` and get only those things I need (disabled controls won't be in there). However, I've found the approach of disabling `FormControl` however, I need to disable whole group.

That's my group

```
formGroup: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
...
        password: this.fb.group({
            current: ['', Validators.required],
            new: this.fb.group({
                password: [{
                    value: '',
                    disabled: this.changePassword.value
                }, Validators.required],
                passwordConfirm: [{
                    value: '',
                    disabled: this.changePassword.value
                }, Validators.required]
            }, {validator: PasswordValidator.MatchPassword})
        })
    });
```

And this doesn't really work. How do I disable the whole `password` FormGroup by attaching disabled state to standalone FormControl (checkbox).

Comment: i think you're looking for ngIf on form

Comment: I've asked about disabled... Check the API of FormGroup `.getRawValue` to understand why I need this

Answer (score 2):

you can open `fieldset` tag inside the `form` tag and use `disable` directive according to the form control value

```
<fieldset [disabled]="changePassword">
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.formGroup.get('password').enable();
        // changePassword: FormControl
        this.changePassword.valueChanges.subscribe(e => {
            if (!this.changePassword.value) {
                this.formGroup.get('password').disable();
            } else {
                this.formGroup.get('password').enable();
            }
        });
    }
```